# startActivityForResult for ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS not triggering onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this method to open app details

```
    public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(final Activity context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    context.startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_APP_DETAILS);
}
```

it works, but when i press back on device and return to my app `onActivityResult` doesn't trigger.
do i need to add anything else to my `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: Do you have this method inside a Fragment?

Comment: yes i do, is that a problem ?

Comment: It's not a problem, but you should have the `onActivityResult` in the Fragment then.

Comment: What is the `context` you are using here?

Comment: im using getActivity().getApplicationContext();

Comment: Posted an answer, check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your call to the `startActivityForResult` is in a `Fragment`, you can use the `Fragment`'s version of `startActivityForResult`. So call

```
startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_APP_DETAILS);
```

instead of

```
context.startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_APP_DETAILS);
```

Then, have your `onActivityResult` in the `Fragment` as well. If you also have overridden `onActivityResult` in your `Activity`, don't miss a call to `super.onActivityResult(...)` in that.

Comment: yep that was it, i was using activity context instead of fragment context